# attach() inside function

Tags: r, scoping

I'd like to give a params argument to a function and then attach it so that I can use a instead of params$a everytime I refer to the list element a.

```
run.simulation<-function(model,params){
attach(params)
#
# Use elements of params as parameters in a simulation
detach(params)
}
```

Is there a problem with this? If I have defined  a global variable named c and have also defined an element named c of  the list "params" , whose value would be used after the attach command?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Noah has already pointed out that using attach is a bad idea, even though you see it in some examples and books. There is a way around. You can use "local attach" that's called `with`. In Noah's dummy example, this would look like

```
with(params, print(a))
```

which will yield identical result, but is tidier.

Comment: +1 Worth explaining what `with()` and `within()` do. In the example given, `with()` creates an environment from `params` and then evaluates the expression `print(a)` _inside_ that environment. Hence the components of `params` are visible when the expression is evaluated, without needing to `attach()` them.

Comment: Thank you very much for the lucid answers.

Comment: So what worked in the end was 'myFun <-function(model,params){with(params),{...}}' where ... is the function body

Answer (score 11):

Another possibility is:

```
run.simulation <- function(model, params){
    # Assume params is a list of parameters from 
    # "params <- list(name1=value1, name2=value2, etc.)"
    for (v in 1:length(params)) assign(names(params)[v], params[[v]])
    # Use elements of params as parameters in a simulation
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Easiest way to solve scope problems like this is usually to try something simple out:

```
a = 1
params = c()
params$a = 2
myfun <- function(params) {
  attach(params)
  print(a)
  detach(params)
}
myfun(params)
```

> The following object(s) are masked _by_ `.GlobalEnv`:
>
> `a`

```
# [1] 1
```

As you can see, R is picking up the global attribute `a` here.

It's almost always a good idea to avoid using `attach` and `detach` wherever possible -- scope ends up being tricky to handle (incidentally, it's also best to avoid naming variables `c` -- R will often figure out what you're referring to, but there are so many other letters out there, why risk it?). In addition, I find code using attach/detach almost impossible to decipher.

Answer (score 0):

Jean-Luc's answer helped me immensely for a case that I had a data.frame `Dat` instead of the list as specified in the OP:

`for (v in 1:ncol(Dat)) assign(names(Dat)[v], Dat[,v])`