# Subtly different behaviour between with() and attach() in R?

Tags: r

People often use the `attach()` and `detach()` functions to set up "search paths" for variable names in R, but because this alters global state that's hard to keep track of, [people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310247/in-r-do-you-use-attach-or-call-variables-by-name-or-slicing/1311620#1311620) recommend [using `with()` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797797/attach-inside-function/5800785#5800785), which sets up a temporary alteration to the search path for the duration of a single expression.

However I just noticed that unlike `attach()`, **`with()` apparently doesn't "resolve through" functions**.  For example, let's first set up a dummy function that will access a variable named `x`:

```
f <- function { print(x) }
```

Now,

```
with(list(x=42), f())
```

fails even though

```
with(list(x=42), print(x))
```

and

```
attach(list(x=42))
f()
```

both succeed! :(

Can anyone tell me why?  I would like `with()` to behave exactly like `attach()` does here, to enable me to effectively pass a big parameter list to a function by setting up an environment containing the parameter values with `with()`.  I see this approach as having several benefits over the alternatives (the two I've considered are (a) laboriously passing all the parameters into the function, and (b) explicitly passing in a list/frame of parameters as a function argument and having the function itself call `with()`), but it doesn't work.  I find this discrepancy pretty troubling to be honest!  Any explanation/help would be appreciated.

I'm using R 2.11.1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference between what `with(list(x = 42), f())` is doing and what you expect is the difference between *lexical scoping* (which is what R uses) and *dynamic scoping* (which seems to be what you are expecting).

Lexical scoping means that *free variables* (like the variable `x` in `f`) are looked up in the environment where `f` is *defined* -- not the environment `f` is *called from*.

`f` is defined in the global environment so that is where `x` is looked up.

It doesn't matter that `with` has been invoked to create a new environment from which `f` is called since the environment from which its called is not involved in looking up free variables.

To get this to work the way you want create a copy of `f` and reset its environment since that is what R uses to search for free variables:

```
with(list(x = 42), { environment(f) <- environment(); f() })
```

Admittedly this is a bit onerous but you could simplify it somewhat by using the proto package since `proto` resets the environment of each function that is explicitly inserted into a proto object:

```
library(proto)
with(proto(x = 42, f = f), f())
```

ADDED:

Note that if your aim is to do object oriented programming (as per your comment to another response) then you might want to look into proto further at the [proto home page](http://r-proto.google.code).  For example, we could define the proto object `p` and redefine `f` so that its a method of `p` (in which case it must accept the object in argument 1) like this:

```
library(proto)
p <- proto(x = 42, f = function(.) print(.$x))
p$f()
```

ADDED 2:

With the attached case, running `f()` first looks in the global environment since that is where `f` is defined.  Since `x` is not found in the global environment it looks into the parent of the global environment and in this case it finds it there.  We can discover the parent of the global environment using `parent.env` and here we see that the attached environment has become the parent of the global environment.

```
> attach(list(x = 42))
> parent.env(.GlobalEnv)
<environment: 0x048dcdb4>
attr(,"name")
[1] "list(x = 42)"
```

We can view the global environment and all its ancestors in order like this:

```
> search()
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "list(x = 42)"      "package:stats"    
 [4] "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices" "package:utils"    
 [7] "package:datasets"  "package:methods"   "Autoloads"        
[10] "package:base"
```

Thus `"list(x = 42)"` is the parent of the global environment, stats is the parent of `"list(x = 42)"` and so on.

Comment: Thanks. "free variables are looked up in the environment where `f` is *defined*" makes sense to me on its own, but if that's true I don't understand how `attach()` enables `x` to be looked up.  I've been assuming that there's a dynamic "stack" of environments that constitutes the "search path", with the topmost searched first etc.  But is the "search path" actually separate from this stack?  Is there no stack at all!?

Comment: @j_random_hacker, See ADDED 2 which I have just now added.

Comment: Thanks, after reading the relevant pages of the "R Language Definition" a few times it finally clicked!  I thought `attach()` *pushed* a new environment on *top* of a stack of search paths, but actually it puts it underneath the global environment (which is where `f()` is defined) -- and that is what allows `x` to be seen via `attach()`.

Answer (score 7):

I *think* this is due to you not defining any arguments to `f`, and thence how the `x` required for `print(x)` is looked for.

In normal use `f()` will look for `x` in the global environment if it isn't supplied (and it isn't nor can it be as `f` takes no arguments).

Inside `with()`, what happens is that any arguments needed for `f` will be taken from the `data` argument. But because your `f` doesn't take any arguments, the `x` in the list is never used. Instead, R reverts to usual behaviour and looks up `x` in the environment of `f`, the global environment, and of course it isn't there. The difference with `attach()` is that it explicitly adds an object containing an `x` to the search path that is in the global environment.

If you write your function properly, following the mantra that you pass in any and all arguments you use within the function, then everything works as one would expect:

```
> F <- function(x) print(x)
> with(list(x = 42), F(x))
[1] 42
> ls()
[1] "f" "F"
```

If you already have the list or arguments need for the call, perhaps consider `do.call()` to set up the call for you, instead of using with. For example:

```
> do.call(F, list(x = 42))
[1] 42
```

You still need your function to be properly defined with arguments, as your `f` doesn't work:

```
> do.call(f, list(x = 42))
Error in function ()  : unused argument(s) (x = 42)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I appreciate that there's risk in not specifying the arguments to `f`, but I thought this approach would be nice because `with(z, f())` allows `f()` to treat `z` a bit like an object of a class -- it can treat its values like member variables, with handy terse syntax to access them.  `do.call()` is handy too, thanks, though I'll probably just use an explicit parameter to cut down on obfuscation.

Comment: @Tommy That's good to know. Wish my wife said things like that ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The description from `?with` states:

> Evaluate an R expression in an environment constructed from data,
>   possibly modifying the original data.

This means that the function is run in an evironment where the data exists, but the environment is not on the search path. Thus any functions run in this environment will not find data that isn't passed to them (since they are run in their own environment), unless instructed to look at the `parent.frame`. Consider the following:

```
> f <- function() print(x)
> f()
Error in print(x) : object 'x' not found
> with(list(x=42),f())
Error in print(x) : object 'x' not found
> x <- 13
> f()
[1] 13
> with(list(x=42),f())
[1] 13
> f2 <- function(x) print(get("x",parent.frame()))
> f2()
[1] 13
> with(list(x=42),f2())
[1] 42
```

To clarify how `with` is normally used, the data is passed to the function in the environment `with` creates, and not normally referred to as a "global" variable by the function being called.

Comment: Thanks, but the part I'm stumbling on is the idea that an environment can somehow exist without being on the search path.  I was thinking that whenever R looks up a variable name, it looks through a stack of environments (which are just lists or frames that happen to be currently on R's "environment stack") until it finds a match, with a "global"/"default" environment at the bottom (similar to how variable names are looked up in lexical scopes in many languages).  If that's true then I don't see how R can "miss" the `list(x=42)` frame but still see the global one!

Comment: You need to specifically `attach` an environment to put it on the search path.

Comment: What I mean is: if an environment is *not* on the search path, then what does it *do*?  I.e. what effect does it have? :)

Comment: @j_random_hacker it has no effect, it is just another R object. The objects inside the environment are just like any other objects inside lists or data.frames that are also not on the search path. R can see an environment in the global environment, but not *inside* that environment.

Answer (score 3):

Passing parameters list works for me:

```
f <- function(params) with(params, {
    print(x)
})
f(list(x=42))
# [1] 42
```

But you should consider explicit refrences, e.g.:

```
f <- function(params) {
    print(params$x)
}
```

Cause in development phase, with lots of variables it's a matter of time when you do something like:

```
f <- function(params) with(params, {
    # many lines of code 
    print(x)
})
x <- 7
f(list(y=8))
# [1] 7 # wasn't in params but you got an answer
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already considered your first suggestion as my alternative (b).  I may wind up using it though as it seems the best workaround in the absence of a "working" (according to my definition) `with()`.  As I said to Gavin, I realise there's a risk in "passing parameters invisibly" but it does (or rather would) allow a nice tight syntax for accessing "member variables".